# Applied for one position and referred by a friend to another in one company

Tags: new-job

I've been looking for a job and recently had an interview for a lab in a company they make a panel of people who they call if a position opens up. That was a general CV I sent to HR months ago and got called for an interview so I'm waiting to hear back.

My friend that works in the same company but in a different lab told me they were looking for someone an handed my CV to her manager. Just before I was called for the interview for the other lab. He emailed me saying they were working with HR in relation to the position. This was a day after the interview.

Should I email this guy back to tell him I had an interview for another lab or just leave it and see what happens?

I'm qualified for both different labs and don't want to mess up both opportunities! If he shows my CV to HR they will see it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with applying for both positions. Just make it clear when applying for the second you've applied for the first and let them know the status of your application.

As it stands now it's probably in your best interest to make the manager of the second lab aware of your first interview with the company. As they've emailed you giving you an update on the status of the position (working with HR) I'd send a reply back just clearly stating the situation. That way you're covered by having informed them as much as you can.